# LTSpice IV: How to vary input Voltage and measure the frequency?

Tags: ltspice

I am getting started with LTSpice IV and I have a couple of beginner questions:

In the following circuit, I want to do the following (separately for each simulation):

1. Vary the amplitude of V1 from 20 volts to 200 volts in steps of 10.
2. Vary the frequency of V1 from 60 Hz to 300 Hz in steps of 10.

In both cases, I want to measure the frequency of the voltage across R2.

Please suggest me how to do this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWVs1Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks.

Comment: The hard bit is getting the oscillations to flow when the frequency changes but that is still possible. It's also possible that you can create a user defined waveform from excel and convert to a CSV then copy and past the data into a special file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a circuit like yours the frequency of any voltage or current will be that of the source signal, hence there is no need to retrieve it from the simulation result. If your situation is much more complex, e.g. you want to measure the frequency of some resonant ringing or the like, you will have to do this graphically from the output plot of a transient simulation.

Now to your question:
If you want to vary several parameters and execute a simulation with every possible combination of these you need to make a parametric simulation. To do so, add the relevant parameters with arbitrary values to your netlist. You can do this by adding the following SPICE directive:

`.PARAM
+ pAmplitude = 20
+ pFrequency = 60`

Also add the following directive to make you transient simulation a parametric one:

`.STEP PARAM pAmplitude 20 200 10` Change pAmplitude from 20 to 200 in steps of 10

`.STEP PARAM pFrequency 60 300 10` Change pFrequency from 60 to 300 in steps of 10

To include the parameters into your schematic simply replace the amplitude value of V1 by `{pAmplitude}` and the frequency by `{pFrequency}`.

Comment: Thanks christoph. How can I measure the frequency graphically? Also, is there any SPICE directive to measure frequency?

Comment: Just plot the quantity whose frequency you want to measure and add two cursors to it. Place the two cursors one period from each other (only works in transient simulation where t is on the horicontal axis), in the small window you can then read out the time difference and the frequency (one over time difference). And no, there is no spice directive to measure frequency directly.